# Merge dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I have an List of dictionary as,

```
input = [{"id":2, "color":"green"}, 
         {"id":3, "color":"red"}, 
         {"id":2, "gender":"male"}, 
         {"id":3, "food":"ice_cream"}, 
         {"id":1, "food":"fish"}]
```

and my expected output as

```
output =[{"id":1, "food":"fish"}, 
         {"id":2, "color":"green", "gender":"male"}, 
         {"id":3, "color":"red", "food":"ice_cream"}]
```

Is there a simpler way to do this than several nested for loops?

Comment: If you want to IMPROVE some code, try [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). **Either way**, if you want an improvement of what you have, **post your code**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @wim's solution is the cleanest, another possibility is to use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
import functools
input = [{"id":2, "color":"green"}, {"id":3, "color":"red"}, {"id":2, "gender":"male"}, {"id":3, "food":"ice_cream"}, {"id":1, "food":"fish"}]
new_input = [functools.reduce(lambda x, y:{**x, **y}, list(b)) for _, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(input, key=lambda x:x['id']), key=lambda x:x['id'])]
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'food': 'fish'}, {'id': 2, 'color': 'green', 'gender': 'male'}, {'id': 3, 'color': 'red', 'food': 'ice_cream'}]
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need *nested* looping, just a simple for loop will do the trick:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> output = defaultdict(dict)
>>> for d in input_:
...     output[d['id']].update(d)
...     
>>> output.values()
dict_values([{'id': 2, 'color': 'green', 'gender': 'male'}, {'id': 3, 'color': 'red', 'food': 'ice_cream'}, {'id': 1, 'food': 'fish'}])
```

Now you may sort the output values by `id`.

```
>>> [output[k] for k in sorted(output)]
[{'food': 'fish', 'id': 1},
 {'color': 'green', 'gender': 'male', 'id': 2},
 {'color': 'red', 'food': 'ice_cream', 'id': 3}]
```

If the data is large, and you want to avoid the final O(n log n) sorting step, you can pre-iterate the input to find the list of ids, and keep things at linear complexity (this is similar to a [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)).

If you insist to do it with `groupby` (which is less efficient and less readable), you can get it a lot cleaner than the monstrosity in the accepted answer.  Try this instead:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import ChainMap
k = itemgetter('id')
output = [dict(ChainMap(*group)) for _, group in groupby(sorted(input_, key=k), k)]
```